# Click one link disables other in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I would like to disable all other links except the clicked one after I click one of the links.

Here is my code so far:

**JavaScript**

```
$(".link-chart").click(function($e) {
    if($(this).find(".link-selector-two").hasClass('red')) {
          $('.link-selector-two', this).addClass('cssclass');
          $('.link-selector-one', this).addClass('cssclass');
    } else {
      $('.link-selector-two', this).removeClass('cssclass');
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link-chart lx-link-chart">
  <div class="link-selector-one">
    <div class="link-selector-two red">One</div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="link-chart lx-link-chart">
  <div class="link-selector-one">
    <div class="link-selector-two red">Two</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

So the idea is for example if I click the first link to disable the second one, if I click again the first link it will deselect the first link in the way it is working now so the second link will be available for selection again. The same option is for the second link if I click the second to disable the first one.

Any help will be welcome to let me know in which approach have to go.

Comment: Look at toggleClass and .not(this)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? where the links link to? do you really need them? if they can be replaces by a different element you could use the disabled property as suggested.

Comment: I would like to disable the <a href""> element. The rest of the links not the selected link. Once clicked again to restore the links.

Comment: I got that. My question was, what are these links? Do they link to another page? According to your code they don't, since the href is "#".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

#### JS

```
var $linkChart = $('.link-chart');

$linkChart.click(function(e) {
  $linkChart.each(function() {
    if (e.currentTarget !== this) {
      $(this).toggleClass('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

#### SCSS

```
.link-chart { 
  &.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/696ek104/1/) to show it in action. FYI, I added a third link so that you could see it'll work exactly the same for as many links as you want to add.